# Issues when starting coordinator in ArangoDB using the Starter

Tags: cluster-computing, ubuntu-16.04, arangodb

I am trying to create a cluster with three servers in Arango, by following the procedure stated in:

https://github.com/kvahed/arangodb-cluster-admin-course/blob/master/part-one.md

This give me some issues, when the Starter tries to start a coordinator (on all servers). I get the following error after running the `arangodb` command:

```
Error while starting coordinator: Cannot start coordinator, because port 8529 is already in use.
```

I guess this is just because Arango after installation is already listening on this port. (Agents and Dbservers are started without problems). So I stop this service by `service arangodb stop` and run the command `arangodb` again.
This just results in the following error:

```
Failed to get master URL, retrying in 5sec (All 3 attemps resulted in temporary failure)
```

which is an issue I have seen some other people also experienced, when shutting down Arango.

My guess is that there is some simple configuration I am missing. I just can not figure it out.

I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04 servers on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just a port clash. If you would like to use this installation for a cluster, please stop and disable the single instance service like so:

```
sudo systemctl stop arangodb3
sudo systemctl disable arangodb3
```

After that your coordinator on port `8529` should do fine.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. And also thanks for the youtube tutorials. I am looking forward to Part 2 and 3.

Comment: Of course. Part 2 is uploaded today. Would be awesome, if you accepted the answer. :)